# How to take a picture using native camera with Appium?

Tags: android, protractor, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I'm currently writing automated tests for an Android app. Til now everything has worked fine. However, I'm now clicking on a button that launches the native camera app. I want to take a picture on the android device and click the ok button after it. But the elements don't appear in the WebView, where I normally inspect the elements.

I tried the following things according to my research and suggestions from other people, but none worked:

```
  it('user takes a picture', async () => {
    browser.sleep(2000);
    //browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform(); 
    /*browser.actions().
    mouseMove({x: 0, y: 100}).
    click().
    perform(); */
    //await browser.pressKeyCode(27);
    //await browser.pressKeycode('27');
    //await browser.driver.pressKeyCode(27);
    //await browser.key_event(27);
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB, 
    protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
  });
```

This is how the tests before look like (which work perfectly fine):

```
  it('user is now able to click the continue button', async () => {
    await page.waitForButton(page.continueButton);

    let button: WebElement = await page.continueButton.getWebElement();

    expect(await button.isEnabled()).toBeTruthy();

    button.click();
  });

  it('user clicks on "take picture" button', async () => {
    await page.waitAndClickButton(page.takePictureButton);
  });
```

Here is a picture of the WebView in Chrome, after clicking on the take picure button:
[The Tab is inactive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MhiD.png)

And this is what I want to achieve: [Take a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSUZE.png) and [save it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6gpO.png).

Comment: did you found the solution? I am having the same issue

Comment: Did you try to capture a photo with:

androidDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent().withKey(AndroidKey.CAMERA)); ?